# Setting up a UIImageView subclass between loading from a NIB and willMoveToSuperview:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIImageView subclass (AdImageView) placed in my view controller's NIB. This AdImageView knows how to go off and load a remote image into itself using some asynchronous calls invoked from willMoveToSuperview. I know this works because if I add the AdImageView through my own code and tell it before it gets added to a super view which image to load it works great. However when switching setup to use a NIB, I'm not sure when to set the remote path on the AdImageView.

I can't do it in any of the VC's init methods, because the NIB objects aren't yet setup. By the time the VC's viewDidLoad gets called AdImageView's willMoveToSuperview: is already called. I tried setting some IBOutlets telling AdImageView who to ask for the image url, but that is also called after AdImageView's willMoveToSuperview:.

I could start the remote image loading in AdImageView's awakeFromNib, but I want to continue to also have the option to programmatically add an AdImageView to a view controller. Putting the code there then puts me in a situation where I could remote image loading reinvoked in willMoveToSuperview: unless I protect it with some sort of flag that just feels ugly.

So where does state setup code for Interface Builder objects normally occur?

(Sorry there is no code for this question, but it's more about strategy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really sound like a `view`'s job but you could do something like this

```
@interface AdImageView : UIImageView

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *path

@end

@implementation AdImageView

- (void)setPath:(NSString *)path
{
  if (_path != path) {
    _path = [path copy];
    [self loadAd];
  }
}

- (void)didMoveToSuperview
{
  [super didMoveToSuperview];

  [self loadAd];
}

- (void)loadAd
{
  // This will only load when the view is on screen
  if (self.window) {
    // ... fetch ad etc
  }
}

@end
```

Comment: I agree this is way more logic to jam into a UIView than I really should, but I didn't want to litter remote requests in every view controller that wants to have an ad. Also turning the whole thing into a view controller of its own felt like a sledgehammer when I could live with a little hack. Any other approaches are welcome too. I'll give your code a try in the meantime, thanks!